# LEFT JOIN query returning double results

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

Good evening,

I am using a LEFT JOIN to query **atable** and **btable**, but when I run the query, I get back each result twice. (Only when I have duplicates)

My Query is as follow:

```
$sql="
SELECT *
FROM atable A
LEFT JOIN btable B ON (A.article_number = B.article_number)
WHERE A.article_number2 = B.article_number2
";
```

**atable**

```
Name   id  name       article_number article_number2
Row1   1    Mercedes     M1                M2
```

**btable**

```
Name   id  name       article_number article_number2
Row1   1    Mercedes     M1                M2
Row2   2    Mercedes     M1                M2
```

Acually I should get this results:

> Mercedes: 1x
>   Mercedes: 1x

I get this:

> Mercedes: 1x
>   Mercedes: 1x
>   Mercedes: 1x
>   Mercedes: 1x

Am I missing something?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing your database structure and contents

Comment: Of course Robbie. I am sorry. Very tired. I will update the topic. Thanks

Comment: @ Robbie Averill
I just update my topic. I hope you can help. I googled more than 2 hours.

Comment: You don't need to specify the joining condition in both `ON` and `WHERE`. It should just be in `ON`. But this has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: @Barmar They are not the same. I used article_number & article_number2

Comment: Still, both conditions should be in `ON`.

Comment: You have two columns named `name` in your tables.

Comment: Yes. Is that the cause of the problem?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I tried your query and I just got 2 rows.

Comment: No, that's not the cause of the problem, because it won't even let me create the tables with duplicate column names.

Comment: I assume those aren't the real column names, and you just made the mistake when you were making fake data for the question.

Comment: Where does `1x` come from in the results? There's nothing like that in the input tables.

Comment: You are right about the names. The real names are not the same (purchase_name - sales_name)
1x means once (Count). That means 1 input on that date.

Comment: Can you do a better example? We know that this is fake data, but can you at least provide a clearer picture of your tables?

Comment: @Ronald Thank you for your reaction. Binit Ghetiya has the solution. I was tired to see that. GROUP BY A.id did the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL is all most correct you just need to add GROUP BY into your sql query.

```
SELECT *
FROM atable as A
LEFT JOIN btable as B ON (A.article_number = B.article_number)
WHERE A.article_number2 = B.article_number2
GROUP BY A.id
```

Here **A.id** is a primary_key of your table **atable**.

Hope this works for you :)

Comment: Thank you very much. It works for me:) Thank you for your time